# How to insert to particular index in elastic NEST

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am new to Elastic so I am little confused I have an index already in elastic by the name of survey and I want to add records into it. I know how to do it using BulkAsync

```
var response = await elasticClient.BulkAsync(b => b
                .Index("survey")
                .IndexMany(data)
            );
```

but I dont know how to do it if I am inserting only one record.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `Index` method like follow

```
await elasticClient.IndexAsync(new Document { }, s => s.Index("survey"));
```

another option is to use `IndexDocumentAsync`, but this method uses the default index defined in connection settings of the client

```
await (new ElasticClient(new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(..)).DefaultIndex("survey")))
    .IndexDocumentAsync(new Document { });
```